# What's the meaning of this operator `=>` in verilog

Tags: syntax, verilog, operator-keyword

I am going through some code of a processor [zet](https://github.com/marmolejo/zet). However, I am stuck here; I cannot make sense of some code like this:

```
if (FROMCE)
  ( CENeg => DQ0 ) = tpd_CENeg_DQ0;
```

I google about the `=>` operator, but I got nothing useful.  Can someone help me?

Comment: https://github.com/marmolejo/zet/blob/master/boards/altera-de1/sim/s29al032d_00.v#L489 Codes were here

Comment: You should google the nearest keywords that appear before: `specify` or `specparam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a state-dependent module path delay. If `FROMCE` is true, there is a path from `CENeg` to `DQ0` with a delay of `tpd_CENeg_DQ0`.
See the examples in the 1800-2017 LRM section 30.4.4.2